# Create mysql database from a config file for deploying Spring App on AWS OpsWork with Chefbook via S3

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, amazon-s3, aws-opsworks

I am deploying a Spring Application on AWS OpsWork via a Chefbook read from an S3 bucket.Currently, I first have to create the mysql database called **messagegateway**. My application.yml file is as follows:

```
# database configuration
spring:
  jpa:
    show-sql: false
    generate-ddl: false
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none

  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql:thin://localhost:3306/messagegateway
    username: root
    password: mysql
    driver-class-name: org.drizzle.jdbc.DrizzleDriver
```

However, I want to create the messagegateway database from a script instead of manually creating it. I tried adding the following code snippet at the top of the InitialSetup.sql script (which creates the tables required by the application):

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS messagegateway;
```

However, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
            Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.FlywaySqlScriptException
                Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException
```

Any leads on how can I create the database via a script or configuration file?

Comment: looks like you might be using the wrong driver. You're specifying mysql but flyway is using h2.

Comment: @locus2k sorry forgot to mention, im using h2 for running the tests, and the error above is thrown by all the tests after i run ./gradlew clean build. I have the following dependency added in my build.gradle to specify using h2 for the tests :testCompile('com.h2database:h2')
Is this approach wrong?

Comment: I dont think so but I haven't used H2 database mostly just mysql. Just saw that it was getting an H2 connection and the datasource was pointing to mysql. Thought that mightve been the issue.

Comment: Are you actually using Flyway or is it being called a different way?

Comment: @locus2k Flyway is present in the project as a dependency. It is declared in build.gradle : compile("org.flywaydb:flyway-core") . I have forked a legacy project to develop my application so a lot of dependencies have been carried forward from it.

Comment: And that is the only exception it gives? It doesnt give what the state was ?

Comment: @locus2k the exception is thrown in the following call: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Unable to obtain Jdbc connection from DataSource

Comment: Think it still has something to do with it trying to connect to a mysql instance when you are using H2 for your tests.